# Honeycomb code on version 1.6

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to take the code example written for 3.1, and make it compile and work on 1.6 and up.
For example - how can I have code example "[Honeycomb Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html)" work on 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to rewrite the Honeycomb gallery program to use the compatibility library and have it work on 1.6 with a different layout, e.g. a single pane one.

The compatibility library is somewhat limited, e.g. in areas such as the customisation of the actionbar, so you'll have to bring in whatever bits of 3.1 you'll need from that and code accordingly so that you don't load anything that you shouldn't when running under 1.6.

The compatibility library sample sources have various fragment samples, although I don't have them to hand to see if they support running on 1.6, probably some of them do.

**Edit** The compatibility library API demos sample does support a miniumum SDK version of 4 (1.6).

Answer (score -1):

You can't, the code for 1.6 will work on higher api's but not the other way around.

Comment: But what about this link: http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/02/strategies-for-honeycomb-and-backwards.html

Comment: Quote from link:
"The good news is that we **PLAN** to have the same fragment APIs available"

Comment: Also what is the use of building in 3.1 if your only gonna use the 1.6 api's?

Comment: I want to build my app with new features of Honeycomb for devices that support it, and show another interface for lower versions. Are you saying it is not possible?

Comment: Nope, you can't use the 3.1 api unless you declare a min. api level. And a 1.6 device won't accept an app with a higher min. api level

Comment: Actually not sure you can have the app run differently for different versions like you can for screen sizes and such... Has to be compatible with a version or not...